# How to get the screens order in Windows with Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've tried get the screens order (like configured in Windows) with the `Screen.screens` method, but it's doesn't work... Here is the order that I get:

```
01, 02, 03, 10, 09, 04, 07, 08, 05, 06
```

But the order of the Windows is:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10
```

Screenshot:

[image]

> "Teste Monitor" is a Adobe AIR application.

How to get the correct order of the screens with as3?

Comment: Where are those numbers coming from?  The 'identify' button in the Windows display settings?

Comment: Yes... I make the comparison of the "Identify" order of Windows with the order that the array appears, but the numbers are not the same as the monitors ...

Comment: Imagine I have ten monitors side-by-side. The numbering order is different when I press "Identify" and when I display the Array index of the `Screen.screens` object

Comment: I added a screenshot to help.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make the screen index match the Windows identifier if it doesn't already (for me they always match, but that's only ever with 2 or 3 monitors). You could probably do so with an ANE which you could write in C# or another Windows friendly language.   What you can do, is resort the screen array into a new array based off each screen's bounds `x` property to match your 1 through 10  from left to right screenshot.

Comment: I did this, I created an object that does the mapping of monitors according to their x and y coordinates, in rows and columns. The problem is that it is still not correct. When changing the Windows numbering, for example `10, 09, 08, 07, 06, 05, 04, 03, 02, 01` the order with the x and y coordinates will be incorrect in the same way. But it should be enough for now.